# How to solve provider string problem in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I'am having a hard time changing the input value of a widget https://pub.dev/packages/stepper_counter_swipe.
I need to init the parameter *initialValue* to the quantity behind *stockQuantity*.
I got this error :

```dart
The following _CastError was thrown building _InheritedProviderScope<ProductManagmentModel?>(
    value: Instance of 'ProductManagmentModel', 
    listening to value):
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast
```

With the following code

```dart
Selector<ProductManagmentModel, bool>(
builder: (_, manageStock, __) {
return Column(
    children: [
    if (manageStock)

        StepperSwipe(
        initialValue:stockQuantity1,
        speedTransitionLimitCount: 3,
        firstIncrementDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        secondIncrementDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        dragButtonColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        withSpring: true,
        maxValue:1000,
        minValue:0,
        withFastCount: true,
        stepperValue:widget.val,
        onChanged: (val) {
                model.product?.stockQuantity = int.parse(val.toString());
            },
        ),

    Row(
        children: [
        Checkbox(
            value: manageStock,
            onChanged: (val) {
                model.updateManageStock();
            }),
        Text(S.of(context).manageStock),
        ],
    ),
    ],
);
},
selector: (_, provider) => provider.product!.manageStock),
```

This is how the *stockQuantity1* value is set up

```dart
void _initController() {
    final product =
        Provider.of<ProductManagmentModel>(context, listen: false).product;
    productNameController.text = product?.name ?? '';
    regularPriceController.text = product?.regularPrice ?? '';
    salePriceController.text = product?.salePrice ?? '';
    sKUController.text = product?.sku ?? '';
    stockQuantity.text = product?.stockQuantity.toString() ?? '';
    shortDescription.text = product?.shortDescription ?? '';
    description.text = product?.description ?? '';
    tagsController.text =
        product?.tags.map((e) => e.name).toList().join(',') ?? '';
    stockQuantity1 = (product?.stockQuantity.toString()?? '') as int;
    //stockQuantity1 = product?.stockQuantity as QuantityInputType;
  }
```

When the checkbox is not checked, the value is null and i get this error. When the checkbox is checked, I don't have that problem.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Your code is not very easy to read. Please create a reproducible version with which we can help you identify the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you include your product model?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps explain your use case a bit more.

You are saying "When the checkbox is not check the value is null and i got this error when the checkbox is checked i dont have that problem"

So the problem actually happens when `product?.stockQuantity` is `null`?

What should the initialValue be when `product?.stockQuantity` is `null`?

From your code it seems that when `product?.stockQuantity` is `null`, `stockQuantity1` becomes an empty string (`''`). Perhaps change that part such that it is `0`:

```
stockQuantity1 = (product?.stockQuantity.toString()?? 0) as int;
```

Comment: Thank you @BJW I solved my problem by setting when `stockQuantity ` is `null` the value 0 for the widget since the widget that I was using only accepts int values.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the following

```
if(product?.stockQuantity.toString() == 'null' ||product?.stockQuantity.toString() == null || stockQuantity.text == null || stockQuantity.text == 'null'   || stockQuantity == 'null'  || stockQuantity == null) {
  //stockQuantity1=0 as int;
  stockQuantity1 = (product?.stockQuantity ?? 0);
}
else  {
  stockQuantity1 = (product?.stockQuantity ?? '') as int;
}
```